# Visual Block Substitution vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm want to indent the comments at the end of each line of the next code:

```
Point d_test = Point(5,-1);    //inCircle > 0
Point e_test = Point(5,-1);  //inCircle > 0
Point f_test = Point(5,-1); //inCircle > 0
Point g_test = Point(4,-5); //inCircle = 0
Point h_test = Point(3,-2); //inCircle < 0
Point i_test = Point(5,0); //inCircle < 0
Point j_test = Point(5,0); //inCircle < 0
```

I'm trying to use visual block selection, selecting the block with comments. Then I try to use substitution like this one : :'<,'>s/\%V^\s+\%V//g

I've made several attempts but no success :( . I bet there is a better way to do this.

The end result I'm looking for is:

```
Point d_test = Point(5,-1);   //inCircle > 0
Point e_test = Point(5,-1);   //inCircle > 0
Point f_test = Point(5,-1);   //inCircle > 0
Point g_test = Point(4,-5);   //inCircle = 0
Point h_test = Point(3,-2);   //inCircle < 0
Point i_test = Point(5,0);    //inCircle < 0
Point j_test = Point(5,0);    //inCircle < 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: There are plugins for that: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align f.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately aligning isn't something you can easily do with just a plain substitute command, as the amount of spaces to insert or remove varies line by line.

I particularly like to solve this problem with [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align), where you can indent the comments using `:EasyAlign /\/\// {'ig': []}`

Edit: Easy Align ignores comments by default. Therefore, to align comments, you have to actually change the `ignore_groups` parameter. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Nice plugin. It just played around with it. It's wonderful. Anyway, it seems that EasyAlign does not operate on text highlighted as comments, ie, when syntax highlighting is enabled. From documentation "Delimiters highlighted as comments or strings are ignored by default" Do you know a way to workaround this behavior?

Comment: You can provide the ignore group parameter as an empty list.

Comment: `:%EasyAlign /\/\// {'ig': []}` @PabloBurgos

Comment: Another approach is to use the operator. Try this: `gggaG<c-g><c-/>//<cr>`

Comment: <c-g> changes the ignore group option, <c-/> inputs a regex pattern

Comment: Using your suggestion does not align comments. Anyway adding 'String' to ignore_groups as    :%EasyAlign /\/\// {'ig': ['String']}   
  changes for the whole file. Given I just want to align selected text under Visual Model     :'<,'>EasyAlign/\/\//ig['String']     do the trick....Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve that using a macro.

Assuming the cursor is in the first line in normal mode, then:

`j
qa0f;10a [Esc]32|dwjq
5@a`

Should format all the lines.

The way this macro works is:

- `qa`: record macro in buffer `a`
- `0`: move to start of line
- `f;`: find the `;` character
- `10a [Esc]`: insert 10 spaces, go to normal mode
- `32|`: move cursor to row 32
- `dw`: delete current word (extra spaces till next word)
- `jq`: move to next line and finish macro recording
- `5@a`: apply macro recorded in buffer `a` five times

Hope this helps.